# Uber-style rideshare/taxi services in Mongolia?

Tags: taxis, mongolia, mobile-apps, ride-sharing, ulan-bator

What are my options for **rideshare/taxi apps in Mongolia**? I'm specifically interested in Ulaanbaatar, but happy to entertain broader answers.

Goal: an app that lets me specify pickup and dropoff locations without needing to speak Mongolian and offers clear pricing or at least a dependable estimate before I book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the best answer from the local foreigner: now there is an app like that! It's called UBcab and it's available in english. The price is quite fixed and easy to locate where you are etc. The arm sticking thing is literally a danger so better use official taxis or just walk if it's downtown the place is so cramped that taxi could be a waste of money. But ofc usually taxi, cars are safer.

https://www.ubcab.mn/

Answer (score 5):

The answer appears to be **none: they're not allowed!** There was a local startup called EasyRide, but per [their last post on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/EasyRideMN/photos/a.1640410919542265.1073741828.1628653150718042/1903504383232916/?type=3&theater), they were "requested" to "pause" by the Mongolian Taxi Services Association on July 1st, 2017.

Answer (score 4):

Hello no need for an 'app' in UB or anywhere in Mongolia, go near the side of the road and stick your arm out. Lots of local people will often just stop and take you where you want. Arm yourself with a tourist map of UB which is readily available around the city.  Do a point and smile and it is a great way to meet local folks. Give them between 2000 and 4000 Mng and you're sweet.
See you in Mongolia

Comment: Most UB guides I've read warn about drunk drivers and ripoffs when using unofficial taxis.

Comment: It looks like s/he is advocating hitchhiking, not unliveried cabs.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It's not hitchhiking if somebody takes you to a destination of your choice and you pay them for the service.